# jQTouch flicker on iPad with pixel doubling

Tags: iphone, ipad, jqtouch

I'm using jQTouch on an iPhone application and one of our requirements is to make this work in the iPad with pixel doubling.  I believe there's a bug/issue with jQTouch on the iPad (running within an app UIWebView, but pixel doubled) that causes the screen to flicker during transitions. Pretty much every transition has a stutter/flicker on it. Has anyone else experienced this?  I also started seeing this flicker on some Android devices as well.

Answer (score 0):

Mobile Safari on iPad has some very gnarly painting issues. When we were developing Sencha Touch, we had to work around a crapload of them. Also jQTouch isn't really tested for iPad.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look here:

http://code.google.com/p/jqtouch/issues/detail?id=301#c27

- Comment 27
- Comment 48
- Comment 49

From Comment 27:

```
  // HACK
  if (animation.name === "slide") {
    var toStart = 'translateX(' + (backwards ? '-' : '') + window.innerWidth + 'px)';
    fromPage.css('webkitTransform', toStart);
  }
  // /HACK
...
  // HACK
  if (animation.name === "slide") {
    fromPage.css('webkitTransform', '');
  }
  // /HACK
```